# magento 2 - How to create a custom "admin" block and display it on an existing Admin page?

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.1, blocks, custom-block

I need to create a custom "admin" block and display it on any admin "product edit" page **in Magento 2.1.x**.

But I also want to be able to display it **on any admin page**, if I need.

Which block classes do I have to extend ? What is the folder structure for admin blocks ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Traditional location for admin blocks is (Example):

```
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Block/Adminhtml/...
```

If you'd like to use block with phtml template you'd like to extend

```
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
```

It is valid both for backend and frontend blocks

The template for your block should be located under:

```
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/<area>/templates/...
```

Where `area` can be:

- `adminhtml` for backend
- `frontend` for frontend
- `base` for both

Then you can add the block to any page using layout. I.e. for product edit page the layout file should be:

```
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml
```

The example content of such layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\Example" name="example_block_name" template="YourVendor_YourModule::example.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Use `referenceContainer` or `referenceBlock` name to define where exactly you want your block to be displayed on a page.
Use layout name (that is based on MCA or simply URL) to define which page will be updated with your block. `default.xml` layout is included on all pages.

Comment: maybe extend \Magento\Backend\Block\Template