# Magento2 - missing adminhtml custom block after upgrade to 2.2

Tags: module, layout, blocks, adminhtml, magento2.2

We had a custom block injected in the adminhtml section. This block is managed in a module (let's call it Vendor/Module) & it was working fine in **Magento 2.1.***, following this methodology [magento 2 - How to create a custom "admin" block and display it on an existing Admin page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152355/magento-2-how-to-create-a-custom-admin-block-and-display-it-on-an-existing-a)

After upgrading to **2.2** the block has disappeared

I have checked for the concrete layout (in our case `sales_order_view.xml`) for any structural changes in the new version, but containers & blocks look the same as we had in **2.1.***

Any ideas for this?

This is the concrete layout file which worked fine in **2.1.***

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\View\Form" name="our_unique_block_name" template="Vendor_Module::our_template.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**UPDATE**

**Bounty**: provide XML code to inject a block inside `sales_order_view` adminhtml layout, explaining how to place it in different sections of the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nero Phung](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/54154/nero-phung) [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/216899/3566) was a good try, and led me to the real problem, looking for all `sales_order_view` appearances in the **vendor** folder

**2.2** version adds **Temando_Shipping** module, which overrides `sales_order_view` layout

**vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="order_tab_info">
            <block class="Temando\Shipping\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\View\Info" name="order_info" template="Temando_Shipping::sales/order/view/info.phtml">
                <container name="extra_customer_info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

So I could recover our custom block (using same XML layout as the one we used in **2.1.***) just by adding a module dependency

```
<module name="Vendor_Module">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Temando_Shipping"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Great work Raul, this saved me a lot of time debugging the same issue in our module on 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see. Magento has added a new container inside block named `order_info`:

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" name="order_info" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/info.phtml">
    <container name="extra_customer_info"/>
</block>
```

So you can try to use this code below:

```
<referenceContainer name="extra_customer_info">
     <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\View\Form" name="our_unique_block_name" template="Vendor_Module::our_template.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: I have noticed that layout change in 2.2, but I wasn't sure it should affect... anyways, I have tried changing to <referenceContainer name="extra_customer_info"> but block still doesn't appear

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/216961/3566

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with **referenceContainer**?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="order_info">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\View\Form" name="our_unique_block_name" template="Vendor_Module::our_template.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the change? Why using referenceContainer to reference a block?

Comment: I use referenceBlock to modify block class (eg change template) and referenceContainer to include over blocks. And it work's

Comment: But... I believe you cannot reference a block (using its name) with a referenceContainer instruction