# Magento 2.2.3 rewrite adminhtml template from module not working

Tags: adminhtml, template, magento2.2.3

I have upgraded magento version to 2.2.3. I am trying to rewrite adminhtml template

```
Magento_Sales::order/view/info.phtml
```

Using below code of **sales_order_view.xml** of my custom module

[image]

Also I have tried with below code:

[image]

But both are not working. It was working before upgrade to 2.2.3

Comment: Your code was working in 2.2? or 2.1?

Comment: @RaulSanchez my code is working in 2.1

Comment: @AdrianZ. Yes i am trying to rewrite template Magento_Sales::order/view/info.phtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by using below code of sales_order_view.xml of my custom module

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It smells like the same happened to me here [Magento2 - missing adminhtml custom block after upgrade to 2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216622/magento2-missing-adminhtml-custom-block-after-upgrade-to-2-2)

So, try adding a module dependency

```
<module name="Vendor_Module">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Temando_Shipping"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Comment: Sequence is already in module.xml file <sequence>
   <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
  </sequence>

Comment: Change it with new Temando Shipping module

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/216961/3566

Comment: I have tried it but no luck

Comment: I assume you have run bin/magento setup:upgrade after the code change